# Display url variable from views.py in Django template

Tags: python, django

I want have my *url* come from **views.py** and then I can pass it as variable to `href` tag in template.

**views.py:**

```
context {
    'urlLink': "{% url 'myapp:theURL' %}"
    ...
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<a href="{{ urlLink }}" LINK 1 </a>
```

I have the above and it is not working. I have also tried `<a href="{{ urlLink|escape }}" LINK 1 </a>` but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use something similar to the `{% url %}` template tag in your view code, Django provides the `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()`. The [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function has the following signature:

```
reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None)
```

So in your context:

```
context {
    'urlLink': reverse('viewname')
}
```

Then you can use in your template:

```
<a href="{{urlLink}}">Link1</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

```
context {
    'urlLink': "%s" % reverse('view_name')
}
```

you cannot use `{% url 'myapp:theURL' %}` in views.py since this is a template tag